Reminder/nofication window (e.g. for appointments, tasks, events) does not open automatically (Ubuntu 24.04)
Up to Ubuntu 22.04 a window with the new (and old) reminders/notifications would open automatically in a window, most of the time on top of all windows (in the beginning sometimes even fullscreen, see this AskUbuntu-question). This has helped me to not miss any new notification or reminder.
In the install of Ubuntu 24.04 (Wayland) I have the reminder only pop ups briefly and hides then in the notification list (in the top panel).
How can I bring back the old behaviour of automatically opening window with the new (and old) reminder and notifications?

After some more searching, I probably found the solution (I will test it more the next days and weeks).
Open dconf-editor and navigate to org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar and change Notify-with-tray to false (description of setting: When set to true, the reminders are shown only in the notification tray, otherwise the reminders dialog is shown immediately.)
I also set Notify-past-events to true. (Show reminder notification for past events)
This will probably save me from missing more tasks, events and other things I wanted to remind me of.
